# How to convert a 3 digit number to Minute-Second format

Tags: python, datetime, time

In my basketball sim, the quarter clock is set to a 3 digit number, 12 minute quarters * 60 seconds = 720 seconds. After the result of my play,  I subtract a random number, in-between 10-24, from the quarter clock. I print the result of my play, as well as the quarter clock.
Example code:

```
quarter_clock = 12 * 60
time_runoff = random.randint(10,24)

def play():
    if player_makes_shot:
    print("player makes the shot")
    quarter_clock = quarter_clock - time_runoff
    print(quarter_clock)
```

output:

```
player makes shot
702
```

How can I make the clock output to be in a minute-second format like this:

```
11:42
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Convert random time to seconds than back into hour minutes and seconds

Comment: The random time is in seconds. I’m wanting to know how to convert the final output into minutes and seconds.

Comment: I am say convert your original time all to seconds then use a function to return a tuple with hours and minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`divmod`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/divmod.html), which "returns the quotient and remainder after a division of two numbers":

```
>>> divmod(702,60)
(11, 42)
```

So you can do something like this:

```
>>> minutes, seconds = divmod(702,60)
>>> print(f"{minutes}:{seconds}")
11:42
```

---

EDIT:

You can also add a 0 to the left of the seconds in case it is a 1-digit number, e.g.:

```
>>> minutes, seconds = divmod(662,60)
>>> print(f"{minutes}:{seconds:02d}")
11:02
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `time` library here. It's made to do precisely this, and you can put into any format you'd like:

So for minutes and seconds (Ie `12:00`), do `time.strftime("%M:%S", time.gmtime(quarter_clock))`

```
time.strftime("%M:%S", time.gmtime(702))
Out[13]: '11:42'
```

And it's just a simple change in the print statement

```
import time
import random

quarter_clock = 12 * 60
time_runoff = random.randint(10,24)

def play():
    if player_makes_shot:
        print("player makes the shot")
        quarter_clock = quarter_clock - time_runoff
        print(time.strftime("%M:%S", time.gmtime(quarter_clock)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 def convert(seconds): 
      seconds = seconds % (24 * 3600) 
       hour = seconds // 3600
       seconds %= 3600
       minutes = seconds // 60
       seconds %= 60
      return hour,minutes,seconds

 def get_sec(h,m,s):
      """Get Seconds from time."""
     if h==np.empty:
         h=0
     if m==np.empty:
         m=0
     if s==np.empty:
         s=0
     return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)
```

Comment: Pass 0 for hours get the seconds then convert your seconds back to minutes and seconds ignoring hour